# Android Splash Screen Bug

Tags: android, android-activity, screen, splash-screen

I display a splash screen for about 3 seconds before my first Activity is called. Splash Screen is also an Activity, after 3 seconds it finish()es and starts FirstActivity. 
Also I have set screen rotation of splash Activity to portrait view.

Now when I test my app it works fine, but during those 3 seconds of splash screen if i change screen rotation, my First Activity is called two times.

Is there any way / code snippet that could help me open my First Activity only once, despite screen rotations when Splash Screen Activity is at foreground. ? Thanks for helping :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not really a bug. When you change orientation the current activity is created again, hence why your SplashActivity is called twice.

I wrote a blog post about handling orientation changes manually; http://c0deattack.wordpress.com/2010/12/25/dealing-with-screen-orientation-changes-manually/

Comment: I know when you change rotation the current activity is created again, thats why to prevent that I have added android ScreenRotation in my manifest file. So it should now open two times.

Comment: "I have added android ScreenRotation in my manifest file"....What does that mean?

Comment: Thanks for helping , apparently its a bug in the emulator. When I tested on the real device it works fine. All I added was android:screenOrientation="portrait" on my Splash Screen Activity to stop it from the rotation. It works on device. The screen does not rotate on the emulator as well but it calls onCreate again two times :( Buggy emulator...

Comment: I meant android:screenOrientation="portrait" , so that it doesnot go in landscape mode during splash screen activity is running.

Comment: Ah yes, when I was writing my blog post I was like "WTF! Why isn't this working" when I was using the emulator. Glad my post helped anyway.

Answer (score 3):

I also had this 'bug'. Here it describes how I solved it: [Activity reloads when orientation changes in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4364545/activity-reloads-when-orientation-changes-in-android)

Comment: Nah it is doing the same thing , during the time the splash screen is displayed if you rotate the device its FirstAppActivity is called twice.

Comment: Thanks for helping , apparently its a bug in the emulator. When I tested on the real device it works fine. All I added was android:screenOrientation="portrait" on my Splash Screen Activity to stop it from the rotation. It works on device. The screen does not rotate on the emulator as well but it calls onCreate again two times :( Buggy emulator...

Answer (score 1):

I think your thread of splash screen gets call again one more time.

So simply set a flag to check screen rotated or not. If yes than do not call this thread again. eg.

```
boolean yourScreenRotationFlag=false;

if(!yourScreenRotationFlag)
{
    // your splash thread code
}
```

and on rotation of screen set this flag to true.

Comment: Thanks for helping , apparently its a bug in the emulator. When I tested on the real device it works fine. All I added was android:screenOrientation="portrait" on my Splash Screen Activity to stop it from the rotation. It works on device. The screen does not rotate on the emulator as well but it calls onCreate again two times :( Buggy emulator...

Answer (score 0):

you can solve it by add this xml attribute to the `Splash` Activity in the `Mainfest`

`android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"`

it prevent your activity from Re-create when orientation occured